# How to customize a view in Drupal 7 using wildcard for the URL

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, wildcard

I'm using "views" to customize the output of every single blog page.
I know I need some kind of wildcard. I am also using clean URLS but am unsure if a wildcard can be used on an alias.

There is only 1 user who will be posting blogs.

Using an alias I would like to apply this custom view to every page under this URL:
http://www.esselaw.com/blogs/ 
For example: http://www.esselaw.com/blogs/blog-entry1 & http://www.esselaw.com/blogs/blog-entery2 and so on.

Since there are other pages that I don't want to apply this view to, I don't want apply this view to anything in this URL format:
http://www.esselaw.com/node/...

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can achieve with the following approach:

First Create a view on the same principale as the taxomony term view (`admin/structure/views/view/taxonomy_term/edit`).

The specific setup shall be :

- Path settings shall be : `/node/%`
- Contextual fitlers : nid with the following setup in the fieldset "When the filter
  value IS in the URL or a default is provided" : select validor 'content' then
  choose your content type. This shall restrict the view to the content
  type selected

When done, setup a custom url pattern for your content type using the pathauto module.